# How to enable WebRTC with Icecat?

Tags: chat, gnu-icecat, jitsi-meet

I am trying to use the [Jitsi Meet](https://meet.jit.si/) web chat service with Icecat, but I am having problems (Icecat is derived from Firefox, but is more privacy/security focused). If I go to [test.webrtc.org](https://test.webrtc.org/), it tells me that it can't access my webcam or microphone, despite the fact that I have given permissions in the preferences for that URL to access both.

Does anyone know how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but try going to `about:config` and then entering `media.peerconnection.enabled` and enabling it

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news on this one, but I don't think getting `icecat` to work with `webrtc` is possible without a lot of engineering.

If you disable all of icecat's privacy settings and disable librejs, and load the test.webrtc.org page, it will access the camera and attempt to start webrtc, but it will soon crash. I consistently and repeatably get this error each time the webrtc test is accessing my camera on icecast.

```
out of memory: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFE610 bytes requested
[Parent 557465, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error (56): Connection reset by peer: file /home/ruben/git/gnuzilla/output/icecat-60.7.0/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 342
[Parent 557465, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error (62): Connection reset by peer: file /home/ruben/git/gnuzilla/output/icecat-60.7.0/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 342

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x160080,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv
```

If you're determined not to use Chrome or Firefox, and want to focus on privacy while still having everything work, I think Brave may be your best bet for right now. Of course there are dozens of niche Chrome and Firefox forks like Waterfox, Pale Moon.

Even though these forks may have slightly better privacy options in some ways, maintaining a completely browser is a major engineering undertaking and it's extremely difficult for these forks to try and stay up to date on security issues.

Meanwhile, the latest Firefox versions are quite privacy focused. I used Brave for a few years but switched back to Firefox completely a few months ago.